# How do I restrict the available work items for support desk users in TFS 2010

Tags: security, team-foundation-server

We run TFS 2010 and use the work items. We are migrating the support desk but don't want them to be able to raise bugs, tasks etc - is there a way to lock them down to just issue?  Also despite putting security on the iterations the support desk user is still able to see all the iterations in the project?

Answer (score 1):

1. You can lock down the creation of a work item type by [adding 'not' rule to a transition](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms194954.aspx). In that case you deny a TFS group to be able to execute that transition.
2. Not showing the iterations you don't have security for, is something we hear more often. It is on our backlog to do, but it will not be part of Dev11 (TFS vNext). There is also a [request on UserVoice](http://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio/suggestions/2266453-hide-area-and-iteration-names-users-don-t-have-per) you can vote on if it is important for you. Sorry I cannot do more for you on this topic.

Ewald - TFS Product Group

Comment: Many thanks that's perfect! As a follow up question I have assigned permission to some queries to allow the support group to see them, however when they log into TFS web (they are part of the work item only group) they cannot see those queries, but only see the "work items i own".

Comment: That is by design. The Work Item Only group is a special group for people who want to log bugs and track those bugs. Those people don't need a CAL to access TFS (it is the license-free workflow in TFS). All other features are turned off for this group.